# Replace a stereo amplifier component

Tags: amplifier, audio

I would like to replace the tda2822m stereo amplifier on a music keyboard because it fried. Problem is I'm not sure which one to use. Some kind of reference is written on the component: wx14a08y. I don't know what it means exactly. I keep finding amplifiers with other references, but I'm not sure they will work. How could I find out?

Here a picture of the PCB with the fried amplifier:

[image]

Comment: Off topic ! If the fried chips says: TDA2822m you can try replacing it with a TDA2822m. The wx14a08y marking means **nothing**, ignore it. Unless you prevent/fix whatever made this TDA2822m blow up, the new one will also blow up.

Comment: Some gnarly cold solder joints there. I see that you removed a 4-wire ribbon in the lower right corner there, too. Just a note.

Comment: I can't see the problem. I had a problem related to an electronic component, asked a question about it and got a satisfying answer. Given question could be useful to others people unexperimented in electronics. So what's the matter about that question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually all you will need is the part number. TDA2822M is a legit number and should get you want you need. The other number is probably the lot number or something irrelevant for your purposes. BTW, make sure you've fixed whatever let the magic smoke out of your old one before you fire up the new one...

Comment: It was plugged in with the wrong power supply. 12V instead of 6V...

Answer (score 1):

The TDA2822M datasheet does not show any variations, so any TDA2822M you can find should be OK.  The wx14a08y label you show is probably a date code and manufacturing location.

The datasheet indicates that this is an obsolete product.